# swapping values in contiguous indices using return method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, swap

I’m trying to swap values in even location with values in odd location .
I have to use Call statement to get the output then return and then use a toString() to show the result. 
For instance: input = 5,1,4,0
Output= 1,5,0,4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accomplish this task with a simple loop, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array2[] = new int[] { 5, 1, 4, 0 };
    int[] swap = getSwap(array2);
    System.out.println("Swapped array is " + Arrays.toString(swap));

  }

  public static int[] getSwap(int[] input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i += 2) {
      int temp = input[i];
      input[i] = input[i + 1];
      input[i + 1] = temp;
    }
    return input;
  }
```

, output

```
Swapped array is [1, 5, 0, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see the (incorrect) output when you provide examples like this. However, I believe I can see what's wrong.

First of all, it looks like you're a little confused with how arrays work in Java. Arrays are not copied unless you explicitly create a new array. In your `main` function, you have two `int[]` variables, `array2` and `swapp`. However, these are both references to the same array! If you print out each one (after calling `getSwap`) you'll see that they have the same contents.

If what you wanted was a *copy* of the array passed in that has the even/odd elements swapped, then you need to create a new array. This can be done like so:

```java
int[] outputArray = new int[inputArray2.length];
```

Second, it looks like you're confusing even/odd **locations** with even/odd **elements**. In fact, I think you're doing both? You definitely don't want the `if(inputArray2[i]% 2 ==1)` line if you're swapping even/odd locations. That line will check whether or not the **element** is even or odd.

Third, to be honest, it looks like you're throwing code out in hopes that *something* will work. In general, when programming, the best approach is to solve the problem first, then write the code. In this case, you need to decide how to swap the even/odd locations of an array first. I don't think you've done that yet. However, you're pretty close! The code inside the if statement is on the right track.

I would encourage you to sit down and try to solve the problem yourself, along with the ideas I've listed so far. However, if you get stuck, feel free to look at what I think would

Here's a quick stab at what the solution may look like:

```java
public static int[] getSwap(int[] input) {
    int[] output = new int[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < input.length; i += 2) {
        int j = i + 1;
        output[i] = input[j];
        output[j] = input[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```